# A fast way to determine if a triangle is rectangular?

Tags: r, dataframe

In a 2-D plane, I have coordinates of three points in a data frame `df` like

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0,3,3),y = c(0,1,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(0,3,3),y = c(0,0,4))
```

Is there a fast way to judge if the triangle is rectangular? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is an easy you want

```
isRectTriangle <- function(df) isTRUE(all.equal(max(d <- c(dist(df))), norm(d[-which.max(d)],"2"),))
```

where a function defined by using `dist`, and ***pythagoras theorem*** is applied to judge.

You will see

```
> isRectTriangle(df1)
[1] FALSE

> isRectTriangle(df2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Rounding will be a problem:  don't compare reals with `==`.  The `all.equal()` function does approximate comparison, and would make more sense.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for the reminder. Now it is fixed.